# How do I copy text from the program "screen" to my clipboard?

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to copy some text from [screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/) to my clipboard. I know how to get into copy and paste mode in screen, but I want that text to go to my clipboard so I can paste it on the browser, for example.

**How do I do this?** Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most programs, you would select text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it. Pasting text would be done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. In the terminal emulator program, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> has a special meaning, it interrupts (stops) programs by default.

Your terminal emulator program may have other shortcuts defined. For example, Konsole and Gnome Terminal uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for copying the selected text. Alternatively, select text and copy it by using the *Copy* option in the *Edit* menu or the context menu.

If the output of your program is large, you might want to enable the scrollback buffer of `screen`. That can be done by adding the below line to the `~/.screenrc` file:

```
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
```

Comment: This won't work if the text you're trying to copy from GNU Screen exceeds the actual screen real-estate

Comment: I usually scroll back then (or just continue scrolling while selecting).

Comment: You mean while in Copying mode in screen?

Comment: Nope, when selecting text in regular mode using the mouse. For that to work, you need to put `termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@` in your ~/.screenrc file to allow scrollback. If you've no .screenrc, get my screenrc from http://lekensteyn.nl/files/screenrc

Comment: Ah, that's it then, thank you for clarification. You may want to add that to your answer.

Comment: I didn't know you could do this with screen. That's very useful and will make copying and pasting quicker for me. While I'm familiar with vim and navigating to the exact point you want to copy, sometimes the mouse is nicer for this.

Comment: For my terminal I needed to add glob match (`xterm*`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125947/6281925).

Answer (score 10):

For a raw and dirty implementation, install the package `xsel`, that allow command line interaction with then X clipboard, then put these lines in your `~/.screenrc`

```
bind > eval writebuf "exec sh -c 'xsel -nbi </tmp/screen-exchange'"
bind y eval "exec sh -c 'xsel -bo >/tmp/screen-exchange'"
```

then restart `screen`.

Now, when you select something in `screen` copy/scrollback mode, and write paste buffer to a file with <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>, you can move to the browser and paste the content of the clipboard as usual (for example with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>).

For the reverse, copy something in your browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, then go to `screen` and read the clipboard with the new command <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd>, then read the screen-exchange file into the paste buffer with <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>, finally paste wherever you want with <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>.

For this to work the variable `DISPLAY` must be correctly set, and you must have access to the X server. This is not a problem when you are on a terminal running on the same X server, but if you run `screen` in a virtual terminal, e.g. tty1, then you may need to run `xhost +` on the X side, and `export DISPLAY=:0` or similar on the terminal, before starting `screen`.

As you see, it is not simple, and not bullet proof, but I hope it can help.

This answer is partly inspired from [synchronizing GNU screen’s paste buffer and the X selection](http://snarfed.org/synchronizing_gnu_screens_paste_buffer_and_the_x_selection)

Comment: The `xhost +` is terrible advice. It allows **anyone on the internet** to hijack your X session, capture your keystrokes, take screenshots, etc. **Never** do it. There are correct ways to do the same thing; as long as you're on the same host and using same homedir, just setting `$DISPLAY` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use copy operation in your terminal application. 
If you are using gnome-terminal for example, just select test and use context menu -> copy.

Comment: What if the terminal application doesn't have a context menu? What if it doesn't have a copy operation? I didn't downvote cause I don't believe it deserves more than one.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04, add this to `~/.screenrc`:

```
bind "^K" screen bash -c "nohup >/dev/null 2>&1 xclip -selection clipboard /tmp/screen-exchange"
```

Note that this rebinds the default kill command bound to `C-a C-k` to something more idiomatic for Emacs users.

See also [a similar answer to do the same thing in Tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117124).

Then restart screen or source the file with `C-a : source ~/.screenrc RET`.

Now typing `C-a C-k` will copy the contents of `/tmp/screen-exchange` to the clipboard.

For example, from an open `screen`, you could use it like this:

- Type `C-a ESC Y` to copy the current line into the paste buffer
- Type `C-a >` to copy the paste buffer to `/tmp/screen-exchange`
- Type `C-a C-k` to copy `/tmp/screen-exchange` to the clipboard

To wrap it all up into one command usable from copy mode, you can also add the following to `~/.screenrc`:

```
bindkey -m "^K" eval "stuff '>'" "screen bash -c 'nohup >/dev/null 2>&1 xclip -selection clipboard /tmp/screen-exchange'"
```

Then the usage is even simpler:

- Make a selection, e.g. type `C-a ESC SPC w` to select a word
- Type `C-k` to copy it to the clipboard