# Is there a program or somehow to get mousekeys on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, default-programs

`Mousekeys` is a feature on Windows that allows you to press buttons on your keyboard and your mouse goes to in a certain direction and certain distance.

Is there a program or built in feature like this in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: does not look like it: http://alternativeto.net/SearchResult.aspx?search=+Mousekeys Old ubuntu method: http://abhijeetmaharana.com/blog/2007/08/31/mousekeys-on-ubuntu/ will not work.

Comment: Mobility impairment sheet for 12.10: http://onlinedocs.info/ubuntu-12-10-mobility-impairments/

Comment: Only thing I found: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68807/how-can-i-configure-mousekeys But this is not moving 'a certain disctance'

Answer (score 2):

There is.

1. Go to **System Settings**.
2. On the bottom left there is a option called **Universal Access**, click it.
3. Navigate your way to the **Pointing and clicking** tab.
4. You should see the option **Mouse Keys**, set this to *on*.
5. Now use the number pad on your keyboard to move the mouse.

The number 1 on your number pad moves the mouse up.
The number 2 moves the mouse down.
Etc.

**Tip:**  All the odd numbers except 5 are used to go diagonal. The number 5 is used to click.