# How to get a command to output the contents into Terminal, and my system clipboard

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, clipboard, alias

Let's say I have an alias on my system which I often use to tell me my system information, the alias is `systeminfo`, and it executes `lsb_release -a` which outputs:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Now because I use this very often, and I then copy and paste the information into my AskUbuntu questions, it would be very useful if upon execution of the command, for the output to not only be printed to the Terminal window, but also be copied to my system clipboard, so that I can save time, and not need to select the text and then copy and paste that here. So I was wondering how that could be achieved? How do I make it so that not only is it printed on screen, but also copied to the system clipboard? Preferably, I would like this question to be answered with a script which asks me if I want the information to be copied to my system clipboard in addition to being displayed on screen, but I can of course write up that script, so it would just be for convenience and to save time.

**Information Update:**

I have tried these, but they don't work for me:

- [How do I pipe terminal standard output (stdout) to the clipboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184397/how-do-i-pipe-terminal-standard-output-stdout-to-the-clipboard)
- [How to efficiently send text entered on the command line to the system clipboard without using the mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64333/how-to-efficiently-send-text-entered-on-the-command-line-to-the-system-clipboard)

Comment: Is this what you want http://askubuntu.com/questions/64333/how-to-efficiently-send-text-entered-on-the-command-line-to-the-system-clipboard

Comment: @Pilot6: Ok, I have tried that and it does not work.

Comment: I tested it and it works. Describe what you did please.

Comment: @Pilot6: I installed it, then did what they said in the answer, and nothing was copied to clipboard.

Comment: What exactly you did? Please [edit] your question and add there the command you ran.

Comment: They work fine for me on the latest Arch Linux as well, so I think you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Worked for me too on 14.04.2

Comment: @Pilot6: Oh that is strange, `xse`l suddenly started working! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install xsel

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Then run

```
cat /etc/lsb-release | xsel -ib
```

And

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

will be copied to clipboard.

You can also output text from clipboard to a terminal command by e.g.

```
xsel -ob | cat
```

Comment: Just as additional info, if you need the clipboard content as input to a terminal command, you do e.g. `xsel -ob | cat` to pipe the clipboard content to `cat` and print it to standard out. Note the `-o` instead of `-i` which means "output" in contrast to "input".

Comment: I will add it. Thx.