# Text selection CTRL+SHIFT+Cursor Keys in shell?

Tags: command-line, guake

I'm using guake and zsh and I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Arrows to select word-by-word, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Arrows to jump around words, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Arrows to select char-by-char in terminal. This is working as expected in applications like gedit.

Is it possible in any shell?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know to select text from a shell without using the mouse is using [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Quick tutorial:

<sup>**Note:** All GNU Screen commands are of the form:  Ctrl+A followed by another key or combination</sup>

1. Install GNU Screen: `sudo apt-get install screen`
2. Open screen: `screen` (or `screen myprog my args here`)
3. Run your program, producing the output you want copied
4. Enter copy mode: Ctrl+A [
5. Move the cursor to a starting point and hit Enter to start selecting
6. Move the cursor to the ending point and hit Enter to finish selection
7. Paste with Ctrl+A ]

**Read more:**

- [How do I copy text from the program "screen" to my clipboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56570/how-do-i-copy-text-from-the-program-screen-to-my-clipboard)
- [GNU Screen Survival Guide - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614/gnu-screen-survival-guide)
- [How do I copy text from my xterm without a mouse - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse)

Comment: Hi, could you expand on this a bit? Link only answers might get you nowhere (if the link goes rotten, or in this case, if the question on SO gets closed/deleted). Add the actual body of your answer in the tekst!

Comment: sorry, I forgot I wasn't on SO! Thanks, I've update the answer.